# HTML5 Boilerplate and multiple files and scripts

Tags: build-script, html5boilerplate

In my project I have multiple html files that I've added to the project.properties like this:

```
# Files can be added in a comma separated form
file.pages        = loginapp.html, docapp.html, adminapp.html
```

The problem is that each of those files needs to load some app-unique scripts. E.g.:

```
<!-- In adminapp.html: -->
<!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
<script defer src="js/mylibs/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/mylibs/knockout.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/helpers.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/app.admin.js"></script> <!-- ** unique for login ** -->
<script defer src="js/app.common.js"></script>
<!-- end scripts-->

<!-- in loginapp.html: -->
<!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
<script defer src="js/mylibs/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/mylibs/knockout.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/helpers.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/app.login.js"></script> <!-- ** unique for admin ** -->
<script defer src="js/app.common.js"></script>
<!-- end scripts-->
```

It works brilliant until I `ant build` it.

It appears that HTML5 Boilerplate's build script has problems with figuring out what's going on here, and it only creates one concatenated file that contains the common stuff, and leaves the rest out (e.g. `app.login.js` and `app.admin.js` get copied into the `publish/` folder, but are not linked to in the minified HTML files (which only link to one script and that's the concatenated one).

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: Is this still a problem with the [new build script](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script)?

Comment: @DivyaManian Sorry, don't know. I went for RequireJS and am using [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/) for building.